# Can the law of entropy decide our fate?

Tags: entropy

Second law of thermodynamics states that entropy always increases.Elixir of immortal life is a thing humans are longing for since ages.Does this law forbid us from becoming immortal?I mean if disorder always increases,then we cannot permanently reverse the process of aging.

Comment: Aging has to do with telomere shortening, in fact there are species with enzymes that repair telomeres, they dont age! . Humans can't do it because it causes us cancer. I dont think it has anything to do with the second law.

Comment: Each time the cell devides it looses part of the telomere, the ending of a chromosome, so when it is too short you cant afford to loose it and cells dont devide.

Comment: The second law of thermodynamics is the definition of temperature. People need to stop interpreting more into it than is in there.

Comment: Entropy is not confined to temperature.It can be applied to various issues.For example when a cup fall down, entropy(disorder is the name we use) increases. A cup that fell from the table cannot join itself and go back to the table.

Comment: Aging is also an increase in disorder. My question whether this disorder can be reversed permanently.

Comment: For what its worth: I want to object the notion that immortality is desirable

Answer (score 4):

Please note that the second law of thermodynamics applies to **isolated systems**. Life, the simplest cell, is an engine for reducing entropy in its volume and increasing entropy in its surroundings, so life is not limited by entropy because it develops within a larger medium, which can be considered as isolated.

Crystals also do the same, when something crystallizes out of e medium, the crystal has reduced entropy and all the entropy increase is in the medium.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by immortal:

If it means to transcend time, can anything wholly mortal or finite transcend time? Even in religous philosophies already some divine element, spark or breath ie something transcendent or immortal in this sense is mixed in with the human clay ie mortal or finite.

If it means to to last as long as time lasts - at least potentially; then that in principle seems possible, by considering some life form that preserves its integrity by excreting entropy to the surrounding environment.